# How to remove the empty space of a non-prefix titlesec

Tags: titles, titlesec, section-titles

How can I remove the space in the first "Conflicto"?:

[image]

I want the first "Conflicto" to have the same indent or horizontal space as the second.
In the first, I'm using \subsection{Conflicto} and I want to still using it. I want to modify format of "\subsection".

This is part of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[top = 2cm, bottom = 1.65cm, left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm}{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\subsection}[hang] 
    {\bfseries\large}{}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Conflicto}
\subsection*{Conflicto}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please never ever post images of code. Provide code that others can copy and test as is. We have no idea what your document looks like, what your class is.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks!!

Comment: Your question is not understood. The example does not include and table of contents, plus you list both subsection and subsection* in the example. Did you mistype in the question and is actually referring to subsection* which does not appear in the toc, whereas subsection does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issued

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries\large}{}{1em}{}
```

which suppresses the prefix/label (number) before the subsection title, since the 4th argument is empty.

However, you are keeping a length of 1em as the 5th argument. That argument is the separator, "the horizontal separation between label and title body" ([documentation](https://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf)). Without the prefix, there is no need for the separator, and in fact, as you found, it sticks out unpleasantly.

To suppress this length, you'd issue

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries\large}{}{0pt}{}
```

However, be aware of the consequences of suppressing the prefix/label that way, as per the documentation:

> You may leave it empty if there is no section label at that level, but this is not recommended because by doing so the number is not suppressed in
> the table of contents and running heads.

If, as it seems, you are looking to *suppress all numbering in subsections* even if they show up in the TOC, there must be safer ways to do that. One way would be to use:

```
\subsection*{Conflicto}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Conflicto}
```

manually for the sections that need to go to TOC.

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to number subsections, set appropriately `secnumdepth`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[top = 2cm, bottom = 1.65cm, left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang] 
  {\bfseries\large}
  {}
  {1em}
  {}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Abc defg}

\subsection{Conflicto}

Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Remove `showframe`, which I used here to better show the placements of the objects.